# iis 7 default page doesn't work

Tags: iis-7

I've set my default page like so but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I've set the config as yours.

Comment: Are you adding this inside the `<configuration>` and `<system.webServer>`?

Comment: Check if this helps - http://forum.winhost.com/threads/setting-the-default-document-page.7577/